# Define CSS Variable w/o Styled Components

Tags: reactjs

I would like to define or update a CSS variable in React. I have seen numerous examples of this using the Styled Components library. Is there a way to set a CSS variable in React without something like Styled Components?

An example would be to update the definition each time state changes

```
useEffect( () => {
    // update css variable
    // --my-css-var: width 75%
}, [state])
```

Comment: Did you mean override a css class?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Also what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this can be accomplished with `style.setProperty()` [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

In React this would require the use of `ref` [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) so we can apply this to a particular element.

```
const reference = useRef(null);
const [state, setState] = useState(100);
useEffect(() => {
    reference.current.style.setProperty('--my-css-var', state);
}, [state]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily set the style. This is an example of setting the style with a function. After one second, the font color is changed.

```
function App(){

  function CanvasStyle(props){
    const [a_color,setColor] = React.useState(props.a_color);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setColor('blue')
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, []);  

    a_style = `
            body {
              color:`+a_color+`;
            }
            `;
    return(
        <>
            <style type="text/css">
            {a_style}
            </style>
        </>
        )
    }

return (
    <>
      <CanvasStyle a_color='red' />
      Hello World!
    </>
  )
}
```